# Usar SweetAlert2 para alterar una variable de clase

Tags: angular, typescript, sweetalert2

Tengo una clase que tiene una variable booleana.
Esta variable define si un usuario recibe una notificación o no, pero quiero utilizar SweetAlert 2 para mostrarle al usuario una alerta preguntandole si desea recibir la notificación o no.

El problema es que la variable, al estar en la clase, al ejecutar una acción en Sweetalert no tengo acceso a ella porque el sweetalert lo hace desde un lambda

```
pauseTimer(event){
    let _sendSmsNotification = false;
    swal({
        title: '¿Desea recibir una notificación?',
        text: 'Podemos enviarte un sms para recordarte cuando el tiempo de este paso esté por terminar',
        type: 'info',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: '¡Si! Quiero recibir un mensaje'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {

            //Acá deseo realizar la modificación a la variable del componente

            swal(
                '¡Anotado!',
                'Pronto recibirás un mensaje de texto al numero que registraste, indicandote cuando el temporizador esté llegando a su fin.',
                'success'
            )

        }else{
            swal('¡Muy bien!',
                'No te molestaremos. Igual si quieres, podemos llevar el tiempo en pantalla para que no se te pase ',
                'success');
        }
    });
```

Necesito poder acceder a la variable del componente desde el Then que hace sweet alert.

Answer (score 0):

Como estas usando una lambda, `this` va a apuntar a tu componente. Entonces puedes accedes a los metodos y propiedades de tu componente desde `this`.

```
   // ... 
   }).then((result) => {
       if (result.value) {
           this.swal(/*...*/);
       }else{
           this.swal(/*...*/);
       }
   // ...
```